# Is it safe to have a web application helper class with static methods?

Tags: c#

I don't like [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) or [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), and I'm an oldschool programmer who uses the old methods through a helper class.

Here is an example of one of my methods to insert data into a database.

```
private class Database
{
    public static void DbInsert(string table, string[] columnNames,
        string[] dataToAdd)
    {
        string tblValues = "";
        string tblRaw = "";
        string tblValuesCN = "";
        string test = "";
        string sql = "";
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataToAdd.Length; i++)
        {
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + i.ToString(),
                dataToAdd[i].ToString()));

            test += dataToAdd[i].ToString() + " --- ";
            tblValues = tblValues + "@" + i.ToString();
            tblRaw = tblRaw + dataToAdd[i].ToString();

            if (i != dataToAdd.Length - 1)
            {
                tblValues = tblValues + ",";
                tblRaw = tblRaw + ",";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
        {
            tblValuesCN = tblValuesCN + columnNames[i].ToString();

            if (i != columnNames.Length - 1)
            {
                tblValuesCN = tblValuesCN + ",";
            }
        }

        sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Insert Into " + table + "(" + tblValuesCN +
            ") Values (" + tblValues + ")";

        sql = "Insert Into " + table + "(" + tblValuesCN +
            ") Values (" + tblRaw + ")";

        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlConn.Close();
        sqlConn.Dispose();
        sqlCmd.Dispose();

        string[] tlCn = {"TableName", "PatientID", "StaffID", "SQL", "DateTime"};
        string[] tlCv =
            {
                table, HttpContext.Current.Session["PatientID"].ToString(),
                HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString(),
                sql, DateTime.Now.ToString()
            };

        DbInsertTL("TransactionLog", tlCn, tlCv);
    }
}
```

Now I'm starting to wonder, is this safe because the method is static? I'm starting to wonder because of a single complaint that something they didn't add was in the database from another user.

I'd hate to instantiate everything from the code behind of the web pages when it's so simple using static methods with this class, but I'll do whatever I have to for integrity.

Comment: Old-school programmer, who writes a code, which is prone to SQL injections? Sorry, man, I don't believe you. :D

Comment: So "old-school" that s/he prefers SQL injection vulnerabilities!

Comment: @ethoen10 it's using parameters if you can read the code, show me where injection will happen.

Comment: If you don't want to use EF, you might want to look at [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) which is a nice Micro ORM.

Comment: Static methods are safe, so long as they don't access static variables.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/): ***What topics can I ask about here?*** *Code Review Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas: Best practices and design pattern usage, Security issues, Performance, Correctness in unanticipated cases*

Comment: I hope Bobby Tables isn't one of your users!! http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: The static method may be safe, but your lack of usings and exposure to SQL injection definitely is not!!

Comment: Example of SQL Injection:  `DbInsert("Users", new string[] {"Userid), VALUES('EvilUser'); DROP TABLE Users;--"} , new string[] {"foobar"})`.  Using parameters doesn't completely prevent SQL injection if you're still generating the SQL statement based on user input.

Comment: @DStanley that's not possible, the sql statement is all parameters, i'm filling parameters with user input not writing statements based on user input.

Comment: @Prospector you are concatenating a list of user-input strings (ColumnNames). If one of those "column names" stings contains correct SQL to complete your statement plus an entirely new statement, you are in trouble. This is what the two strings do that D Stanley is passing in as 'column names'.

Comment: @Prospector if you do not use user input for the _column names_ then my example would not be valid, but my point is just because you are using parameters doesn't mean you're 100% safe from injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Something is safe until some resource is possibly accessed by more than a thread, or one or more threads are accessing unmanaged resources that should be explicitly disposed or they can keep locked ending in deadlocks**.

Now imagine that you declare a `SqlConnection` as static field and a method disposes it while other from other HTTP request was about to execute a command... **CRASH!!**. You would need to synchronize access to your `SqlConnection` instance. You might even implement a connection pool or whatever (well, SQL Server has connection pooling already, it's just an example).

In your case, one of most possible unsafe code, but unrelated with the fact that it's enclosed into a static method, is where you create a `SqlConnection` and you don't use the `using` statement, which provides more safety since you've full guarantee that it'll be disposed after ending the `using` block:

```
// Equivalent to try/finally where finally 
// block will implicitly call SqlConnection.Dispose() for you
// even if some exception is thrown within the using block
using(SqlConnection conn = ...) 
{

}
```

You're potentially creating non-dispoed SQL connections and you might end in overusing your SQL Server connection pool or just crashing your app because there're no more connections available...

Anyway, I doubt your argument *"I like static methods because I hate instantiating classes"* is driving you in the right direction.

C# is a full object-oriented programming language and you should work on creating object graphs, and separate your concerns in an object-oriented way - that is, **you should avoid using classes as just function modules** -.

Maybe you should take a look at the *façade* design pattern. This patterns works on creating a class that might simplify complicated things.

For example, you need to register an user and this means instantiating some domain classes. Since *register user* is a use case, you can simplify it implementing a `UserFacade` which might have a `RegisterUser` method, and this will do that domain operation so higher-level layers won't need to repeat the same code and they will stay agnostic about low-level domain details...

### Update

OP said:

> would you instantiate console.write? it's used in a similar way

Yes, right, there're helper classes which are implemented as static classes.

Your case sounds bad for a static class, because each method is repeating the code to create SQL connections and other details that can be encapsulated and used everywhere in order to avoid code repetion (copy paste programming...).

And you may be opening and closing a connection everytime and you lose the chance to share a connection or send commands in batch.

If you try to implement above suggestions using a static class you'll end in a bunch of unmaintainable methods and spaguetti code because the lack of separation of concerns... Or, at least, we won't be talking about an object-oriented solution...

There're edge cases where you might use a static class. Examples:

- Helper classes (not your case... your case is a low-level data access layer which should be implemented using an object-oriented approach if you insist in using C#).
- Extension methods.
- Factory methods.
- ...

Comment: would you instantiate console.write? it's used in a similar way

Comment: @Prospector There're cases where you implement static classes... Right... :D

Comment: thanks, it took all this reading and I realize it's time for me to get with the times. I'm studying up on entity framework now.

Comment: @Prospector Nice nice! I was going to add a second update suggestion you that using an OR/M would be the best idea. You should take a look at Dapper, the mini OR/M used and created by StackExchange/StackOverflow. It's in the middle point of your old school solution and a full OR/M like Entity Framework.